# How to serve font files under bower_components folders on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Using `Yeoman` webapp generator, I am able to install `bower_components` and execute `grunt` locally. When deploying the app to Google App Engine, I had to add all files served from `/dist` folder.

What changes should be made to `app.yaml` file to serve the font files under `dist/bower_components`?

My `app.yaml` file:

```
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: dist/index.html

- url: /styles
  static_dir: dist/styles

- url: /scripts
  static_dir: dist/scripts

- url: /bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap
  static_dir: /dist/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap


skip_files:
- ^node_modules*$
- ^bower_components*$
```

[image: 404 errors]

Comment: The question is unclear, please specify an actual font path relative to the app's top level dir and which is the path under which that font is to be served.

Comment: Did you mean: /dist/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff ?

Comment: Almost. The leading `/` makes it an absolute path, which likely doesn't exist. But yes, I think I got the location. I noticed you have a leading `/` in your `static_dir` value as well, try to remove it.